# Как что то сохранить в папке на внешнем хранилище на Android 13 Xamarin?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

У меня есть три проекта xamarin.forms,android и ios. Ios на данный момент не входит в суть вопроса. Есть несколько телефонов с разными версиями Android 8,9,10,13. На всех телефонах кроме 13. Я могу получить путь к папке , создать ее и что то там сохранить - любой файл, на всех устройствах Android , кроме версии 13.
Что для этого было сделано:
Самое первое это манифест

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Дальше при запуске приложения, запрос у пользователя на разрешение к чтению и записи или к проводнику в целом. Этот код находится в `MainActivity`. Read, Write, тут прописано , остальное вопроса не касается.

```
   ActivityCompat.RequestPermissions(thisActivity, new string[] {
    Manifest.Permission.PostNotifications, 
    Manifest.Permission.WriteExternalStorage,
    Manifest.Permission.RecordAudio,
    Manifest.Permission.ReadExternalStorage 
}, 1);
```

В основном проекте xamarin.forms я получаю путь к корневой папке хранилища: и создаю путь до папки , которую хочу создать.

```
// Android.OS.Environment.ExternalStorageDirectory.AbsolutePath // Возвращает корневой катлог
 folderPath = Path.Combine(Android.OS.Environment.ExternalStorageDirectory.AbsolutePath, "CorpFiles");
```

В переменной `folderPath` Хранится путь к нужной мне папке.
Дальше я проверяю есть ли папка по этому пути и если надо создаю ее

```
if (!System.IO.File.Exists(folderPath))
      {
         Directory.CreateDirectory(folderPath);
      }
```

Этот код отлично работает до 13 android. Марки телефонов xiaomi, samsung, huawei, bq, и прошитый Redmi Note 8 pro под Pixel с Android 13. Проблема заключается в том, что когда я пытаюсь создать папку, то появляется ошибка access to the path, не смотря на то что все разрешения были выданы. В настройках Приложения на устройстве в разделе разрешения сам по себе пункт доступ к хранилищу отсутствует и даже руками выдать разрешение не удается.  Вот фото настроек "разрешения" приложения. [image: Разрешение]
После этого был найден, если я правильно понимаю "Нативный код". Он работает только в проекте Android. Вызывать его можно будет только через `DependecyService`.

```
var intent = new Intent(Intent.ActionOpenDocumentTree);
StartActivityForResult(intent, 1 );
```

Данный код запускает проводник в котором можно выбрать папку и к ней якобы будет предоставлен доступ. Однако как получить путь к этой папке и как дальше пользоваться, информации ни какой не было найдено. Для примера его можно добавить в MainActivity при запуске программы, что бы быстрее проверить. Вот так выглядит проводник который запускает этот код.
[image: Проводник]

Итак, подводя итог. С основного Xamarin.Forms проекта на Android 13 не удается получить доступ к созданию или сохранению файла. При попытке вызвать проводник через код на Android, нет понимая как  получить выбранную папку и как с ней дальше взаимодействовать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Итак спустя несколько дней поиска был найден весьма понятный ответ, проблема была не в прошивке или моделях телефона. Вот текст из статьи:

*"Одним из требований для Api 29-го уровня было использование Android Storage Access Framework (SAF) вместо простого получения разрешения “WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE”. Однако это требование не было выполнено, поскольку разработчики могли просто добавить android:requestLegacyExternalStorage=”true” в манифест приложения и использовать старый подход.
С новым требованием ориентироваться на уровень API 30 старый подход работать не будет."*

Т.о. android выше 10 версии не дает доступа к созданию папок и файлов во внешнем хранилище. Но если вы по прежнему хотите сделать это вам понадобиться другой инструмент (SAF). вот собственно краткий пример:

```
var intent = new Intent(Intent.ActionOpenDocumentTree);
StartActivityForResult(intent, 1 );
```

С помощью данного кода мы  открываем дерево папок, в котором можем создать новую папку и когда мы ее создадим устройство спросит у пользователя, давать ли нашему приложению доступ к этой папке. Когда нам надо будет сохранить какой либо документ нам надо будет вызвать.

```
Android.Content.Intent intentCreate = new 
Android.Content.Intent(Android.Content.Intent.ActionCreateDocument);
                    intentCreate.AddCategory(Android.Content.Intent.CategoryOpenable);
                    intentCreate.SetType("application/pdf");
                    intentCreate.PutExtra(Android.Content.Intent.ExtraTitle, "invoice.pdf");
    
                    // Optionally, specify a URI for the directory that should be opened in
                    // the system file picker when your app creates the document.
                    intentCreate.PutExtra(DocumentsContract.ExtraInitialUri, sPath);
    
                    StartActivityForResult(intentCreate, 2);
```

Данный код открывает все то же дерево папок, только уже сохраняет документ, если брать за аналогию ОС Windows, то окно будет выглядеть "Сохранить как", где вы сами можете указать имя файла и куда сохранять. Проблема в том, что так нельзя сохранить сразу несколько файлов. Однако разработчикам оставили возможность сохранять папки и файлы в таких папках как Download document DCIM и т.п. без открытия дерева папок. Все тем же старым метод File.Create().

Вот код, благодаря которому можно вернуть путь к папке документы

```
var pathDoc = Android.OS.Environment.GetExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Android.OS.Environment.DirectoryDocuments);
```

Как видите, там можно выбрать любую другую папку.

[image: Сво-ва]

[Вот ссылка на статью](https://medium.com/swlh/sample-for-android-storage-access-framework-aka-scoped-storage-for-basic-use-cases-3ee4fee404fc)